# Why is Wordpress loading a different sized post thumbnail?

Tags: images, post-thumbnails

I have a custom theme where I'm using post thumbnails as BG images for a slider.  The thumbnails and some other info are entered using a custom post type.  However, even though I'm uploading 1440x833 images, the image wordpress loads is always 1024x593.  Why is it even creating a 1024 version of these thumbnails?

Here's the relevant code in index.php.

```
<!-- The Args -->
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'home-slider',
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        );
?>

<!-- The Query -->
<?php $homeslides = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>

<div class="flexslider">
    <div class="slides">
        <!-- Slide 1 -->

        <!-- The Loop -->
        <?php if ( $homeslides->have_posts() ) : while ( $homeslides->have_posts() ) : $homeslides->the_post(); ?>
        <?php $slideimage = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'home-slides' ); $url = $slideimage['0']; ?>

        <div class="slide">
            <div class="slide-image" style="background: url(<?php echo ($url); ?>) no-repeat center center;"></div>
            <div class="headline-container">
                <div class="headline">
                    <h1><?php the_field('slide-title') ;?></h1>
                    <hr />
                    <h5><?php the_field('slide-subtitle') ;?></h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's where I'm declaring the thumbnail size (functions.php).

```
// This theme uses a custom image size for featured images, displayed on "standard" posts.
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
    set_post_thumbnail_size( 320, 180, true ); // primary size
    add_image_size( 'home-slides', 1440, 833, true ); // thumbnail size in home slider
```

}

Thanks for your help!

Comment: well first of all, the admin UI uses the `thumbnail` size, so you probably shouldn't set it to such an enormous size, use the `large` size or add a new size. second- your code doesn't use the thumbnail size, you're requesting `full`. as your code is loading the original size, I'd guess you have some css rules limiting the size.

Comment: Hi Milo - I did exactly what you're saying.  The only CSS I have that even uses 1024px is a media query breakpoint at that point.  I changed my code to use a pre-set size (see updated post). Unfortunately it's still resizing my images.  Note: http://dev.citylightphilly.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/mishkan-chair.jpg - this is the link to the original image, that I uploaded at 1440 x 883.

Comment: also +1 for the point about admin using the thumbnail size - that impacted a few of my themes.  any thoughts why wordpress would resize the original image?